# How to compute a variable or column of comma separated values from multiple rows of the same column

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Scenario**: azure data flow processing bulk records from a csv dataset. for doing dependent jobs at destination sql required a comma separated ids from multiple rows of that csv. Can some one help how to do this.

Tried using derived column step with coalesce, concat functions,  didn't get the result looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collect() aggregate function. This will act like a string agg. It was just released last week.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#collect

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/adf-adds-new-hierarchical-data-handling-and-new-flexibility-for/ba-p/1353956

Comment: Hi Mark, 

collect is good option, but the collect returns an array and I'm having had time to find solution to convert that to a comma separated value to pass on to stored procedure. for this reason i was looking for some other solution. If my target DB is noSQL this have no problem, but my case its MS SQL. any suggestion here is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just follow-up your collect() aggregation with a derived column. Cast the string array toString().